# Finding and showing by class traversing up and down a tree

Tags: jquery

**I have the following structure:**

```
<li>
    <div class="button_holder">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="tag"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="cover" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to click `.tag` and show `.cover`

I'm trying:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag', function() {

    $(this).closest('.button_holder').next('.holder').find('.cover').show();

});
```

But not changing it from `display:none`

Is the correct way to traverse back up a tree and then down to next sibling and in to one of it's children?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/23eVj/1/

Comment: this seems fits better for code review. As it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kaG7g/15/)**
**HTML**

```
<li><div class="button_holder">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="tag">dffd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="cover" style="display:none">ddddd</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.tag', function() {

      $(this).closest('li').find('.cover').show();

    });
```

Comment: Yeah I don't get that either, I've voted it back up, this answer is correct. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/kaG7g/13/)
You are doing correct way, But you missed some content.

```
<div class="button_holder">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="tag">dffd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="cover" style="display:none">ddddd</div>
    </div>
```